# pulling just the text out of a multi variable list. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list in a Change Notifier that is fed in several different types of variables.

```
List<Entries> InfoList = [];
```

and here are the variables being fed in (Entries)

```
class Entries {
  String text;
  Color color;
  int Positioning;
  Entries(
      {required this.text,
      required this.color,
      required this.Positioning});
}
```

what i'm trying to do is display only the text variables from this list in a Text widget.

ive tried:

```
'${context.read<AppProvider>().InfoList[index].text}'
```

which is the same code in the ListView.builder (which works for that perpose) but i get an error on the index saying Undefined name 'index'

how do i pull just the text info from the list?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is the ListView.Builder:

```
ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return DisplayTile(
                          text: context
                              .read<AppProvider>()
                              .InfoList[index]
                              .text,
                          color: context
                              .read<AppProvider>()
                              .InfoList[index]
                              .color,
                          Positioning: context
                              .read<AppProvider>()
                              .InfoList[index]
                              .Positioning,
                        );
                      },
                      itemCount: context
                          .read<AppProvider>()
                          .InfoList
                          .length,
                    ),
```

Comment: Please show your whole `ListView.builder`.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the original post to include the ListView.Builder. what i'm trying to do though, is display the text part of the list in a Text widget in another part of the app. cheers

Comment: Extract a list from provider before ListView.builder and use it inside without reading from context every time. `final infoList = context.read<AppProvider>().InfoList`. Then refactor all usages to previously created `infoList`.

Comment: The error indicates that your variable index doesn't exist or it is out of scope.
Make sure the index variable is in that scope.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Anis Alibegić](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7674734/anis-alibegi%C4%87) comment you should extract a list to use once, I recommend you wrap your ListView.builder with a Selector:

```
Selector<AppProvider, List<Entries>>(
   selector: (context, provider) => provider.InfoList,
   /// check shouldRebuild method if you want to provide another way to validate they're different 
   /// (if the list is created anew each time it won´t fail,
   /// but if you use add or remove the equality check will fail and need to be sure you're updating this widget accordingly)
   builder: (context, entries, _) {
     return ListView.builder(
       scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
       shrinkWrap: true,
       itemBuilder: (context, index) {
         /// or you can receive just an Entries object in your widget and unwrap its data there
         return DisplayTile(
           text: entriest[index].text,
           color: entriest[index].color,
           Positioning: entriest[index].Positioning,
          );
       },
       itemCount: entriest.length,
     );
  },
)
```